# Iterate over rails object and array

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm iterating over a model object @products (currently 3 in the DB), but I also need to apply different styling to each of the objects returned in my view.

Here is my current code in my **page_controller.rb** to get only the first 3 products:

```
@products = Product.where(id: 1..3)
```

In my view **index.html.erb**:

```
<div class="row pricing-table">
  <% @products.each do |p| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel <%= custom-style %>">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="text-center"><%= p.title %></h3></div>
          <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong><%= number_to_currency(p.price, precision: 0) %>/month</strong></p>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center list-no-bullets">
            <%= p.description.html_safe %>
          </ul>
          <div class="panel-footer">
            <%= link_to("Request Quote", "/quote_forms/new", class: "btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger-override") %>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is add a custom style to the 4th line `div` element. *(I've put in erb syntax so you can see where I'm talking about)*

So, I added an array of the CSS style classes to **page_controller.rb**:

```
@style = ["danger", "info", "success"]
```

In hopes that there is a way to get the 4th line `div` element to be:

```
<div class="panel panel-danger">
```

in the first iteration, then in the second iteration:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
```

and so on.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Yes, noted.  I actually need to only get the first 3 from my DB for this particular page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `each_with_index` to iterate over products and then use the index to get the corresponding style name:

```
<div class="row pricing-table">
  <% @products.each_with_index do |p, p_index| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class='panel <%= "panel-#{@style[p_index % @style.size]}" %>'>
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="text-center"><%= p.title %></h3></div>
          <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <p class="lead" style="font-size:40px"><strong><%= number_to_currency(p.price, precision: 0) %>/month</strong></p>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center list-no-bullets">
            <%= p.description.html_safe %>
          </ul>
          <div class="panel-footer">
            <%= link_to("Request Quote", "/quote_forms/new", class: "btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger-override") %>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: if `@products.size` is greater than `@style.size`, `@style[p_index]` will return `nil`... You need to use modulo in this case: `@style[p_index % @style.size]`

Comment: Edited my answer. Thats @MrYoshiji

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the teamwork!  Works like a charm, and I learned something new: `.each_with_index`